# Capifony: How to avoid composer install depedencies in symfony2

Tags: symfony, capifony

I don't need composer vendors update in 90% of deploys because i deploy many times per day. How to avoid composer install depedencies?

I tested some parameters but always ends in

```
 ** [] Loading composer repositories with package information
 ** [] Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Some deploy.rb data:

```
set :branch, "master"
set :repository,  "file:////path/to/git.git"
set :scm,         :git

set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache

set :copy_vendors, true
set :clear_controllers,     false

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml", "composer.phar", "vendor"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]


set :writable_dirs,     ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :permission_method, :chown

set  :use_sudo,      false
set  :keep_releases,  3

set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, false
set :composer_options, "--verbose --optimize-autoloader"
```

Comment: Do you use `install` or `update` command? The first one should be very fast if you won't change any dependencies (`composer.lock` file isn't changed).

Comment: I'm using set :use_composer, true | set :update_vendors, false

Comment: @smoreno did you find a solution ? What about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have `set :copy_vendors, true` but you do not have the directive `before "symfony:vendors:install"`, You do not have them or you just didn't copy in the snippet ?

As you can read from here: http://capifony.org/cookbook/speeding-up-deploy.html

> With default configuration, capifony will reinstall all your vendors for each deploy. If you feel that is inefficient, you can manage to have your vendors just updated, not reinstalled.

Adding the code present in the page above `capifony` **before** running `composer vendor install` copy `vendor` directory from previous release. In these way `composer` does something only if you have changed your vendors.

Comment: No I don't have this directive. It's necessary? Capifony works fine, it use composer update, ect. but I need that composer doesn't update/install at least I declare explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you need it. I've updated my answer. BTW `composer` decide by it self if update vendors or not, it's not safe to leave this decision to the user.